# Run a stage only if one of the deployment tasks fails in one of the stages?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to figure out, but I can't find any supporting documents. Here's the scenario: we have three stages. In the second stage, there's a task where we disable ADF triggers and perform the deployment (AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2). If the deployment fails, the pipeline exits, and the ADF triggers remain disabled. However, after this, we have another stage to re-enable all those stopped ADF triggers. The question is, is there any way to run the re-enable ADF triggers stage only if the deployment task (AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2) fails in the current stage or 2nd stage? Also, if some other task fails in the second stage, the pipeline will exit. Cannot use continueonerror condition.

The deployment stage:

```
steps:

- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Get All ADFTriggers'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.AzureServiceCon }}'
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: '2.2.8'
    Inline: |
      some code
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'

- task: PythonScript@0
  inputs:
    scriptSource: 'filePath'
    scriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/AzurePipelines/YAML/Pipelines/02_ApplicationDeployment/YAML_CD/ADF_CD/reenable-triggers.py'
    pythonInterpreter: 'C:\Python310\python.exe'
  displayName: "Get ADF Triggers"

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/triggerName.txt' #Path to the folder or file you want to publish
    artifact: 'ADFTrgList'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'      

- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Disable adf triggers'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.AzureServiceCon }}'
    ScriptType: 'FilePath'
    ScriptPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/AzurePipelines/YAML/Pipelines/02_ApplicationDeployment/YAML_CD/ADF_CD/PrePostDeployment.ps1'
    ScriptArguments: '-armTemplate "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/ArmTemplates/ARMTemplateForFactory.json" -ResourceGroupName $(paramResourceGroupName) -DataFactoryName $(paramfactoryName) -predeployment $true -deleteDeployment $false'
    preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: '2.2.8'
    azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'


- task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2
  displayName: 'Azure Deployment:Create ADF'
  inputs:
   
    azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.AzureServiceCon }}'
    resourceGroupName: "$(paramResourceGroupName)"
    location: "$(paramResourceGroupLocation)"
    csmFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/**/ARMTemplateForFactory.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/**/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json'
    deploymentMode: ${{ parameters.paramDeploymentMode }}
    enabled: ${{ parameters.paramEnabled }}
    condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

The trigger enable stage:

```
stages:
- stage: ADFTriggers
  displayName: Re-EnableADFTriggers-${{ parameters.environmentShortName }}
  dependsOn: TagSucceededCICD
  condition: |
    and(
      or(
        eq(dependencies.ADFDeploy.result, 'Failed'),
        eq(dependencies.ADFDeploy.result, 'Succeeded')
      ),
      in(variables['environmentName'], 'Prod', 'QA', 'STest')
    )

  variables:
    - template: ../../../YAML/Variables/${{ parameters.environmentShortName }}/variables-master.yml
  pool:
    name: ${{ parameters.agentPoolName }}
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'
    demands:
      - msbuild
      - visualstudio
      - vstest

  jobs:
  - deployment: ADFTrg_${{ parameters.environmentShortName }}
    displayName: ADFTriggers ${{ parameters.environmentShortName }}
    pool:
      name: ${{ parameters.agentPoolName }}
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'
      demands:
      - msbuild
      - visualstudio
      - vstest
    workspace:
      clean: all
    environment: ADF-TRG-${{ parameters.environmentShortName }}
    strategy: 
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps: 
          - checkout: 'YAML'
          - task: AzurePowerShell@5
            displayName: 're-enable adf triggers'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.AzureServiceCon }}'
              ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
              preferredAzurePowerShellVersion: '2.2.8'
              Inline: |
  
                # Check if the trigger name file exists
                $triggerFile = 'triggerName.txt'
                if (Test-Path $triggerFile) {
                    # Read trigger names from the file
                    $triggerNames = Get-Content -Path $triggerFile

                    # Loop over trigger names
                    foreach ($name in $triggerNames) {
                        # Start each trigger
                        # Start-AzDataFactoryV2Trigger -DataFactoryName $(paramfactoryName) -ResourceGroupName $(paramResourceGroupName) -TriggerName $name -Force

                        # Output the trigger name
                        Write-Output $name
                    }
                } else {
                    Write-Output "Trigger name file not found."
                }

              azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
```

Comment: Did you refer to the documentation on conditions? You can specify `failed()` as a condition if you want something to run only on failure. Or `always()` to always run. Or various other scenarios.

Comment: Actually I have seen failed and always but this are not meeting up my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use output variables ([Set an output variable for use in future stages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#set-an-output-variable-for-use-in-future-stages)). Add a new task that adds an output variable after the task failure. Like:

```
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
      - bash: |
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myOutputVar;isoutput=true]run re-enable"
        condition: failed()
        name: enableOutput
```

Then use the in the next job:

```
- stage: B
  dependsOn: A
  - job: B1
    variables:
      myVarFromJobA: $[ stageDependencies.A.A1.outputs['enableOutput.myOutputVar'] ]  
    steps:
    - bash: |
       echo $(myVarFromJobA)
      condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['myVarFromJobA'], 'run re-enable'))
```

Comment: I was thinking of same. Just posted this scenario may be there could be a better way or more cleaner way to do it. Thanks for the answer by the way.

Comment: What if I want to run setvariable task only if certain task is failed. For example this should only run when above task is failed. If some other task is failed then the pipeline should exit.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh that is not an easy task )))..... you may real logs with rest API... or... as 
a workaround... add a new setvariable task with "myoutput.certaintaskfails='false'" after your certain task. therefore, this task will not run if your certain task fails... then use the condition on the next stage `condition: ne(variables['myoutput.certaintaskfails'], 'false')`

Comment: I achieved this with a REST API. I called the REST API to retrieve the exact task status and set the variable if the previous task failed or succeeded. Then, the next task will run based on a condition.